# JS / lodash: Mutate and return data in one line of code

Tags: javascript, lodash

I cannot find an answer for something so simple. How can I mutate an object property e.g. a boolean flag and then return the mutated object in one line of code? As per my example below it now requires two. Everything I read says use map vs for / forEach.

```
   toggleMenu(obj) {
        this.data = _.mapValues(this.data, function(v) {
             v.submenu = (v.submenu ^ (v.id === obj.id));
            return v;
        });
    }
```

UPDATE

I should have added that the return object should / could be different  i.e. `this.other = ...`  versus `this.data = ...`

```
   toggleMenu(obj) {
        this.other = _.mapValues(this.data, function(v) {
             v.submenu = (v.submenu ^ (v.id === obj.id));
            return v;
        });
    }
```

Comment: Do you *have* to mutate the existing object, or can you return a new object?

Comment: @CertainPerformance sorry I should have pointed out that it should / could be different. Important point I should have clarified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to mutate an existing array, and not return a new one, you don't need to reassign the value. In this case it's better to use [`_.forEach()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#forEach) (or [`_.forOwn()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#forOwn) since it's an object):

```
toggleMenu({ id }) {
  _.forEach(this.data, v => v.submenu ^= (v.id === id))
}
```

Comment: `v => v.submenu ^= v.id === id`

Answer (score 1):

Since you're overwriting `this.data` anyway, it looks like you may be able to return a new object. If that's permitted, use object spread and implicit return instead:

```
toggleMenu(obj) {
  this.data = _.mapValues(this.data, v => ({ ...v, submenu: v.submenu ^ (v.id === obj.id) }));
}
```

Can also use `Object.assign`:

```
toggleMenu(obj) {
  this.data = _.mapValues(this.data, v => Object.assign(v, { submenu: v.submenu ^ (v.id === obj.id) }));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code updates the code, but does not `mutate`

The difference is (in most cases) irrelevant. But if you definitely have to update it inplace for some reason, you may want to use 2 lines for better readability than any hack

```
this.data = this.data.map(v => ({...v, submenu: (v.submenu ^ (v.id === obj.id)}));
```

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of:

```
toggleMenu(obj) {
  this.data = _.mapValues(this.data, v => _.extend(v, { submenu: v.submenu ^ (v.id === obj.id)});
}
```

Comment: Btw: Normally, you'd use map / mapvalues, etc. to create a new array / object. Since you're overwriting this.data, Ori Drori's answer is a bit more concise.